# when inserting data using PHP in jquery and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

here below code using insertdata in jquery and ajax is not working please slow this code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#btn").click(function()
     {
      var fname=$("#fname").val();
      var lname=$("#lname").val();
      //alert(fname);
      var URL="insertprocess.php";
      var datastring='fname'+fname+'&lname'+lname;

      $.ajax()
      
     });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: _please slow this code_?? What is your question, I don't get you...

Comment: Have you actually read the docs? `$.ajax();` alone does basically nothing. You need to pass your `URL` and `datastring` vars to the `$.ajax();` function.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here use `=` equal

```
var datastring='fname='+fname+'&lname='+lname;
```

If still getting any issue share complete code